# Sum of all numbers

Tags: python

I need to write a function that calculates the sum of all numbers n.

```
Row 1:          1 
Row 2:         2 3 
Row 3:        4 5 6 
Row 4:       7 8 9 10 
Row 5:     11 12 13 14 15 
Row 6:   16 17 18 19 20 21
```

It helps to imagine the above rows as a 'number triangle.' The function should take a number, n, which denotes how many numbers as well as which row to use. Row 5's sum is 65. How would I get my function to do this computation for any n-value?

For clarity's sake, this is not homework. It was on a recent midterm and needless to say, I was stumped.

Comment: Hint: see the regularity in the leftmost numbers of each row? 1,2,4,7,11,16,...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The leftmost number in column 5 is `11 = (4+3+2+1)+1` which is `sum(range(5))+1`.  This is generally true for any `n`.

So:

```
def triangle_sum(n):
    start = sum(range(n))+1
    return sum(range(start,start+n))
```

---

As noted by a bunch of people, you can express `sum(range(n))` analytically as `n*(n-1)//2` so this could be done even slightly more elegantly by:

```
def triangle_sum(n):
    start = n*(n-1)//2+1
    return sum(range(start,start+n))
```

Comment: I would say the second version is actually slightly *less* elegant, but slightly *more* efficient.

Answer (score 4):

A solution that uses an equation, but its a bit of work to arrive at that equation.

```
def sumRow(n):
    return (n**3+n)/2
```

Comment: I think there is no need for the 'conversion to double than back to int'-idea, as n**3 and n will always have the same parity, thus their sum is always even. You can just simply `return (n**3+n)/2` instead.

Comment: @elias I believe you are correct. Im not sure why I thought I had to convert to double first.

Answer (score 2):

The numbers 1, 3, 6, 10, etc. are called **triangle numbers** and have a definite progression. Simply calculate the two bounding triangle numbers, use `range()` to get the numbers in the appropriate row from both triangle numbers, and `sum()` them.

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum_row(n):
    final = n*(n+1)/2
    start = final - n
    return final*(final+1)/2 - start*(start+1)/2
```

or maybe

```
def sum_row(n):
    final = n*(n+1)/2
    return sum((final - i) for i in range(n))
```

How does it work:

The first thing that the function does is to calculate the last number in each row. For n = 5, it returns 15. Why does it work? Because each row you increment the number on the right by the number of the row; at first you have 1; then 1+2 = 3; then 3+3=6; then 6+4=10, ecc. This impy that you are simply computing 1 + 2 + 3 + .. + n, which is equal to n(n+1)/2 for a famous formula.

then you can sum the numbers from final to final - n + 1 (a simple for loop will work, or maybe fancy stuff like list comprehension) 
Or sum all the numbers from 1 to final and then subtract the sum of the numbers from 1 to final - n, like I did in the formula shown; you can do better with some mathematical operations

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic solution:

```
start=1
n=5
for i in range(n):
    start += len (range(i))
answer=sum(range(start,start+n))
```

As a function:

```
def trio(n):
    start=1
    for i in range(n):
            start += len (range(i))
    answer=sum(range(start,start+n))
    return answer
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def compute(n):
   first = n * (n - 1) / 2 + 1
   last = first + n - 1
   return sum(xrange(first, last + 1))
```